# Which browser plug-ins support cross-domain TCP sockets?

Tags: sockets, plugins, browser, tcp

A feature of my web app requires fetching and parsing html from an unaffiliated, 3rd party website. I want to do this client-side. I already know about server-side proxies. My research has shown that only a self-signed java applet can do this. Flash requires placing a policy file on the 3rd party website (not possible), so that's not much help.

Are there any other cross-platform, in-browser solutions with a large installation base?

Once again, NOT interested in server-side proxies. I just want to know about client-side in-browser technologies which allow cross-domain TCP connections other than java applets.

Comment: If it involves heavy processing, you should do it on the server.

Comment: I don't have the server resources, it MUST be client-side.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much information, but one thing you can do if you must do it in the browser, is to have your browser technology of choice (applet, flash, javascript, silverlight) communicate with your server, and your server make the call on their behalf.

This provides a few benefits, one is that if you ever want to change the 3rd party app, then you just change it on the server.

Some 3rd party sites may not be happy if random clients are accessing them.

This also enables the server to do some processing, to make it easier for the client to do the rest of the processing.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a long time since this question was asked and times have changed since proxy gateways were in vogue.

Two mechanisms other than signed java applets are available to cross domains from an ajax page.

- JASONP
- HTML5 [WebSockets](http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket) with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing ([CORS](http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS))

Answer (score 0):

You can  write a server-side script on your domain that forwards the data from the remote server to the client.

All this costs you is bandwidth.